# Contradiction when derive pdf from cdf and integrate again

Tags: probability, random-variables

I encountered this example on [statlect.com](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/functions-of-random-variables-and-their-distribution) and the screenshot of it is as follows

[image: example]

It took me a while to figure out why $P(X=1)=1/2$. I don't have much experience dealing with distribution functions with both discrete and continuous parts. So I am not sure if it is legal to conclude contradiction does arise when doing the following operations:

PDF of $X$ is $f(x) = 1/2$ when $x \in (1,2)$. In addition $f(1)=1/2$. Therefore $f(x)$ is continuous on $[1,2)$. That makes $\int_{1}^{2}f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$. However, that would make $f(x)$ not a legitimate PDF and it would only make sense to do $\int_1^{2}f(x)+f(1) = 1$. But does it mean we have different results when we integrate $f(x)$ on $(1,2]$ and $[1,2]$? How can this happen?

*Some digression*: I am actually not sure how $f(x)$ should behave when $x=2$ since $F(x)$ can not be differentiated at that point.

Comment: I double checked the picture and the example is the one I am referring to. Could you please point out why you think I am mistaken?

Comment: The random variable isn't continuous.

Comment: The support of $X$ is $[1,2]$. Why is it not continuous?

Comment: You're confusing "pdf" with $X$. Which is different, and "pdf" doesn't exists

Comment: $P(X=1)=\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. the distribution has a jump at that point, so the pdf would have a delta function with weight $\frac{1}{2}$ at that point.

Comment: @dummybear pdf doesn't exist in the normal sense. But you can generalize what is pdf using distributions like Math Lover.

Comment: @Adam Thanks a lot! I will check further materials and look for more examples

Comment: @herbsteinberg Thanks I am checking on delta function

Comment: @dummybear see (correct) answer by Math Lover.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x).$$
Consequently, we have $$f(1) = \frac{1}{2}\delta(x),$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).
Also,
$$\int_{1^-}^{2} f(x) dx = \int_{1^-}^{1^+} \frac{\delta(x)}{2}dx + \int_{1^{+}}^{2} f(x) dx = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}=1.$$

---

For more information, check out [this website](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_3_solved4_3.php) about mixed random variables.

Comment: Huge thanks!! I will check that site.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in general
$$
P(X=a)=P(X\le a)-P(X<a)=F(a)-\lim_{x\uparrow a}F(x).
$$
In your example
$$
P(X=1)=F(1)-\lim_{x\uparrow 1}F(x)=\frac{1}{2}-0=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
To see why $\lim_{x\uparrow a} F(x)=P(X<a)$, observe that
$$
(X\leq a_{n})\uparrow (X< a)\implies \lim_{x\uparrow a}F(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} P(X\leq a_n)=P(X<a)
$$
by measure continuity from below where $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing with limit $a$.

Also $X$ cannot have a density function with respect to Lebesgue measure since $P(X=1)>0$. Integrating a density over a single point must yield zero.

Comment: Can we say the density function of $X$ does not exist at all? Or it is just undefined on $x=1$?